# Flutter Google Maps real time location update when user move

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, location, flutter-dependencies

I am using google maps in Flutter and I am getting the user's current location and showing a marker on that. The map is two markers' one is the user's current location and the other one is static. And I am showing polylines between these two markers. I want that when the user changes its location (the user is moving), the marker and polylines should also move accordingly (Like google Maps when we travel from one location to another). How can I achieve that in my below code?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:custom_marker/marker_icon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'CustomMarker.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController? _controller;
  final GlobalKey myglobalKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey otherglobalKey = GlobalKey();
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

  late String _mapStyle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocationAndPolyPoints();
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/mapStyle.txt').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
  }

  Future<void> getLocationAndPolyPoints() async {
    Location location = Location();
    LocationData currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() async {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          icon: await MarkerIcon.widgetToIcon(myglobalKey),
          markerId: MarkerId('MyLocation'),
          position: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation.longitude ?? 0.0),
        ),
      );

      _markers.add(
        Marker(
            icon: await MarkerIcon.widgetToIcon(otherglobalKey),
          markerId: MarkerId('Destination'),
          position: LatLng(28.4212, 70.2989),
        ),
      );

      _controller?.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation.longitude ?? 0.0),
            zoom: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      );

      getPolyPoints(currentLocation);
    });
  }

  Future<void> getPolyPoints(LocationData currentLocation) async {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      "AIzaSyBI22C6hc7_C4yRuyEnUPHPJGu3k0GH6PU",
      PointLatLng(currentLocation.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation.longitude ?? 0.0),
      PointLatLng(28.4212, 70.2989),
    );
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) => polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Map"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          MyMarker(myglobalKey),
          OtherUserMarker(otherglobalKey),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: GoogleMap(
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 12.0,
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller = controller;
                _controller?.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
              },
              markers: _markers,
              polylines: {
                Polyline(
                  polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
                  points: polylineCoordinates,
                  color: Color(0xFF7B61FF),
                  width: 6,
                ),
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              getLocationAndPolyPoints();
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          child: Icon(Icons.location_searching_rounded, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and this code worked for me.

```html
Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position _newLocation) {
  setState(() {
     //update your marker and polylines with new location data
  });
});
```